# Missing AWS Dependency

Tags: amazon-web-services, synchronization

i had a case where i need to configure an AWS structure similar to the architecture that is described in this [article](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/leveraging-multiple-ip-addresses-for-virtual-ip-address-fail-over-in-6-simple-steps/), is but this article is old, when i followed the steps i couldn't pass the step at which i run the script "vip_monitor.sh".
so be specific, at the step 5 by running the script i got the following error

```
Can't open /etc/profile.d/aws-apitools-common.sh
```

that shell script doesn't exist in the whole machine, how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the OS you are using? any third party?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, it's EC2 instance (Ubuntu 16.04) and no third party

Comment: If I remember this correctly, you need to use Amazon Linux AMI (and not Ubuntu).

Comment: Thanks again, but you see, i need to prepare an environment that it will be used to install applications that are only installed on (Ubuntu 16.04) so isn't there anyway or work around to pass this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually i installed the ec2-api-tools **J.Parashar** instructed, and when i ran the script `vip_monitor.sh` it gave me the same error so i just took the missing script `aws-apitools-common.sh` file from an Amazon Linux instance and paste it at the path `/etc/profile.d/` and then changed the mode to the script to executable `chmod +x aws-apitools-common.sh` and ran the script 'vip_monitor.sh'.

if you had the error `:Unexpected operator` run the script with `bash ./vip_monitor.sh`

Answer (score 1):

You will have to set api tools manually.

Ubuntu makes their own AMI's for Amazon, and they don't build the apitools into the images.

You can use official ubuntu documentation to fix these:
[Install ec2 api tools](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EC2StartersGuide)

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:awstools-dev/awstools
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ec2-api-tools
```